# JS Sortable Tables with linked rows?

Tags: javascript, html

Okay, I have a table. In this table I have a whole bunch of columns, and I would like to use a Sortable Tables javascript so that the user can sort the table as they wish. There are many such JS scripts available (ie: http://tablesorter.com/docs/)

However, the problem I have is that for each row of my table that I want sorted, there is a `colspan="4"` row right below it that I dont want sorted. In fact, I want these rows linked directly to the row above them so that when those rows get sorted, the 4-span row below it sticks with it.

Is something like this possible?

```css
table {
  border: 1px black solid;
  width: 100%;
}
thead {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  text-align: left;
}
.notes {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Command</th>
      <th>DMG</th>
      <th>EXE</th>
      <th>TOT</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Jouho Touken</td>
      <td>19</td>
      <td>17</td>
      <td>42</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4" class="notes">Opponent crouching (H: Stagger)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Chouyoushu</td>
      <td>25</td>
      <td>18</td>
      <td>46</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4" class="notes">Damage varies due to distance (25-40)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tetsuzankou</td>
      <td>40</td>
      <td>19</td>
      <td>75</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4" class="notes">Super Replay; Damage varies due to distance: 40-80</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how you could do this.

- Make an array of all rows in the `<tbody>`.

  - Group it into pairs. `[{data, note}, ...]`
  - Sort by a given sorting function
  - Flatten back into an array of table rows.
- empty the `<tbody>` tag
- Insert into the `<tbody>` tag everything in the sorted table rows array.

```js
var tableBody = document.querySelector('tbody')

var tableRows = Array
  .from(document.querySelectorAll('tbody > tr'))

var notesAndData = []
/* Group elements into
  [
    {data: <tr>, note: <tr>},
    ...
  ]
*/
for(var i = 1; i < tableRows.length; i += 2) {
  notesAndData.push({
    data: tableRows[i-1],
    note: tableRows[i]
  })
}

function flatten(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
    acc.push(curr.data)
    acc.push(curr.note)
    return acc
  }, [])
}

function repopulateTable(arr) {
  tableBody.innerHTML = ''
  arr.forEach(function(element) {
    tableBody.appendChild(element)
  })
}

function sortTable(sortingFunc) {
  /* Spread the notesAndData into a new array in 
     order to not modify it. This syntax is es6 */
  var sorted = [...notesAndData].sort(sortingFunc)
  repopulateTable(flatten(sorted))
}


function sortByDmg(ascending) {
  return function(a, b) {
    var aDmg = parseInt(a.data.children[1].textContent)
    var bDmg = parseInt(b.data.children[1].textContent)
    if (aDmg < bDmg) return ascending ? 1 : -1
    return ascending ? 1 : -1
  }
}

document
  .querySelector('.dmgSort')
  .addEventListener('click', function() {
    sortTable(sortByDmg(true))
  })
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px black solid;
  width: 100%;
}
thead {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  text-align: left;
}
.notes {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<button class="dmgSort">Sort By DMG Ascending</button>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Command</th>
      <th>DMG</th>
      <th>EXE</th>
      <th>TOT</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Jouho Touken</td>
      <td>19</td>
      <td>17</td>
      <td>42</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4" class="notes">Opponent crouching (H: Stagger)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Chouyoushu</td>
      <td>25</td>
      <td>18</td>
      <td>46</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4" class="notes">Damage varies due to distance (25-40)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tetsuzankou</td>
      <td>40</td>
      <td>19</td>
      <td>75</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4" class="notes">Super Replay; Damage varies due to distance: 40-80</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```